# Code first virtual property for relationship still builds with a non-nullable column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

My `Emails` object in my data model has a relationship to `EmailTemplates` but since an Email doesn't *NEED* to have an associated template, I want the relationship to allow null values so I've set up the property in `Email` as a virtual:

```
public class Email
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual EmailTemplate EmailTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

This unfortunately has not set the EmailTemplateId column generated for the FK relationship as nullable so whenever I try to add an email that doesn't use a template, my insert statement violates the constraint.

[image: EmailTemplateId column should accept null values]

How can I modify my data model to allow nulls for this relationship?

Comment: Add this property explicitly: `public int? EmailTemplateId {get;set;}` or modify migration manualy. And `virtual` is not about this.

Comment: The `virtual` modifier has no bearing on properties being required or not. But from what I see, EF should make the FK nullable because that's the default. Are there any additional mappings?

Comment: @GertArnold no, I'm not using Fluent or anything (it confuses me). Sticking to naming conventions to get all the mapping done.

Comment: Which EF version are you on?

Comment: @GertArnold I believe EF6 but I'm not sure. Slava's comment fixed it though, now the email gets inserted without violating any constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `virtual` modifier has no bearing on properties being required or not. You can achieve what you want by adding a nullable foreign key (`int?`) property:

```
public class Email
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmailTemplate")]
    public int? EmailTemplateId { get; set; }
    public virtual EmailTemplate EmailTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

The alternative is to add a mapping in the context's `OnModelCreating` override:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Email>()
    .HasOptional(m => m.EmailTemplate )
    .WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("EmailTemplateId"));
```